# Camunda Support for Content Management Integration u

Tags: camunda

Is there an out of box support for Content Management Systems in Camunda BPM workflow? For example if any of the human tasks If I would like to provide the document attachment functionality, do I need to implement or is it available?

Regards,

Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attachments](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/api-references/javadoc/org/camunda/bpm/engine/task/class-use/Attachment.html) to up/download documents. There is also support for comments. If you just want to pass some docs or notes from task to task, those might suffice.
It's far from "out of the box CMS functionality", though.